# Why/how does named vs wildcard import affect parameters?

Tags: python, import, tkinter, wildcard

So... I'm tinkering with some basic python/tkinter programs, and translating the code from python 2.x in the book I'm reading, to 3.x to make sure I understand everything.  I was also attempting to write the code with 'proper' named imports instead of wild card import i.e. `from tkinter import *` but its not working out so well...

What has me baffled at the moment is this: the original code does a wildcard import of tkinter, and seems to be able to 'get away with' not using quotes around parameter variables like `sticky=W`, while if I do a named import I have to use quotes around the 'W' or I get an error `Unresolved reference 'W'`.

Example code (wildcard import):

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

Label(root, text="Username").grid(row=0, sticky=W)
Label(root, text="Password").grid(row=1, sticky=W)
Entry(root).grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=E)
Entry(root).grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=E)
Button(root, text="Login").grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=E)

root.mainloop()
```

Named import:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

tk.Label(root, text="Username").grid(row=0, sticky='W')
tk.Label(root, text="Password").grid(row=1, sticky='W')
tk.Entry(root).grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='E')
tk.Entry(root).grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='E')
tk.Button(root, text="Login").grid(row=2, column=1, sticky='E')

root.mainloop()
```

Both work, but why does python recognize it one way one time, and not the other?

Comment: Without much familiarity with `tkinter`, my guess is `W` on the top example would be equivalent to a `tk.W` on the bottom one. Did you try that?

Comment: In addition to @mhlester's answer, I assume it also accepts the strings 'N', 'S', 'E' and 'W' as well simply as a convenience.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
from tkinter import *
```

Loads everything from `tkinter` module, and puts it in the global namespace.

---

```
import tkinter as tk
```

Loads everything from `tkinter` module, *and put it all in the `tk` namespace.* So `Label` is now `tk.Label`, and `W` is `tk.W`

---

Your third option, which is better when you only need a few objects from the module, would be:

```
from tkinter import Label, Entry, Button, W, E, Tk
```

Etc. Again, better when you just need one or two. Not good for your situation. Just included for completeness.

---

<sup>Fortunately you only have one `import *` or you'd have a much harder time determining which module everything came from!</sup>

---

### Edit:

```
tkinter.W = 'w'
tkinter.E = 'e'
tkinter.S = 's'
tkinter.N = 'n'
```

They're just constants. You could pass the string *value* and it would work just as well.

Comment: Ah.  I had not tried `tk.W` before, as suggested in your earlier comment - which does work.  I guess where I was having problems was I didn't realize (or think it was even possible) that 'W' was imported (or existed) at the same level as `Label`, `Entry`, `Button`, or `Tk`.

Comment: and thus the hatred of `import *` :)

Comment: Unfortunately almost every tkinter intro/tutorial/book/doc that I've ever seen (with the exception of the one from New Mexico Tech) uses a wildcard import... and I didn't realize *why* that one was different until just now!