# tkinter program freezes when i try to modify the label while switching frames

Tags: python, button, tkinter

I  am trying to build a tool for kitchen order taking. So far i have tried to code the following.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import font  as tkfont
import time
import threading

class RMS_APP(Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.title_font = tkfont.Font(family='Helvetica', size=18, weight="bold", slant="italic")
        self.title("Restaurant Management System")
        self.master = Frame(self)
        self.master.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky='nwes')
        #self.geometry("1600x800+0+0")

        self.master.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.master.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (LogIn, Table,ShowTable):#,Kitchen):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(parent=self.master, controller=self)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame

            # put all of the pages in the same location;
            # the one on the top of the stacking order
            # will be the one that is visible.
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame("LogIn")

    def show_frame(self, page_name,arg = None):
        '''Show a frame for the given page name'''
        frame = self.frames[page_name]


        if arg:
            frame.OnClick(arg)
            #self.label1.grid_forget()
            pass
        frame.tkraise()

class LogIn(Frame):
    #part of code left
    pass

class Table(Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,controller):
        Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = Label(self, text="Choose the table for further details ", font=controller.title_font)
        label.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=(500,10),pady=(100,10))
        No = 1

        for r in range(3):
            gridFrame = Frame(self)
            for c in range(4):
                temp = "Table_"+str(No)
                #self.temp = Button(gridFrame,text = temp,height = 5,width=10,command = lambda temp = temp: controller.show_frame('ShowTable',temp))
                self.temp = Button(gridFrame,text = temp,height = 5,width=10,command = lambda temp=temp: controller.show_frame('ShowTable',temp))
                self.temp.grid(row=r,column=c,padx=10,pady=10)
                No+=1

            gridFrame.grid(row=r+1,column=0,padx=(500,10),sticky='news')
    def test(self,txt):
        print(txt)


class ShowTable(Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,controller):     
        Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = Label(self,text = 'Table : ',font=controller.title_font)
        label.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=(10,10),pady=(10,10))
        self.label1 = Label(self,text = None,font=controller.title_font)
        self.label1.grid(row=0,column=1,padx=(10,10),pady=(10,10))

        back = Button(self,text = 'Back to Tables',height = 5,width=10,command = lambda : controller.show_frame('Table'))
        back.grid(row=1,column=0,sticky='news',padx=(500,10))

    def OnClick(self,arg):
        def callback():
            self.label1.configure(text = arg)
        t = threading.Thread(target = callback)
        t.start()
        t.join()

class Kitchen(Frame):
    pass

class BillTable(Frame):
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = RMS_APP()
    app.mainloop()
```

---

In this after switching to the Table frame and i am trying to pass argumnts to ShowTable frame,to know which table is pressed, but the program freezed when i call label modification. After that gone through some post and tried threading, still not able to fix the code.

Little help needed here to find out what mistake i am doing

Comment: Is the code running for you? it doesn't run for me though.

Comment: i have skipped the class LogIn here to  avoid lengthy description. That might be the issue. Wait i will modify the whole

Comment: @Saad you can try by commenting LogIn in the for loop. Hope that should work

Comment: Do you just want to update `self.label1` in method `OnClick()`?

Comment: @Saad yes bro with that i have multiple function to be carried on. But when i pass arguments to a frame witch it is freezing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using threading with Tkinter is a bad idea specially like this. You can change the text just by

```
def OnClick(self, arg):
    # Two different ways to configure widgets
    # self.label1['text'] = arg    
    self.label1.configure(text = arg)
```

If you have created `OnClick()` just to update the label then you don't even need the method you can simple do `frame.label1['text'] = arg` in your `show_frame()`

```
def show_frame(self, page_name, arg = None):
    '''Show a frame for the given page name'''
    frame = self.frames[page_name]
    if arg: 
        frame.label1['text'] = arg
    frame.tkraise()
```

Comment: i tried this also. But the code freeze is happening. Then only i saw a post to include threading so wrote the function

Comment: The code that you've posted works perfectly with this answer, I checked it. if it is still freezing then it might be with the other part of the code that you haven't posted. Or try `update_idletasks()`. Also [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56036825/edit) your post for more information.

Comment: Yeah looks like it works if i comment other parts of the code. Thanks bro. will look into the other issues happening

Comment: still y the function call freezes the UI any idea how I can call a function inside the frame by button call and argument passing

Comment: @Myjab: You should probably arrange your pages more nicely and accessible your code can be a lot more better first thing always use [`import tkinter as tk `](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22313924/why-how-does-named-vs-wildcard-import-affect-parameters) instead of `from tkinter import *`. I'm getting the freezing of your GUI from your new post but I'm not sure why it is happening probably someone else can point it.